# UITableView Cell Label Duplicating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController full of UITableViews and I use custom cells in a specific one of these.

In `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I add a UILabel with `[cell addSubview:label];`

This works great, however if I then go into the detail view, then return back, it duplicates the label. How can I stop this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. How can we fix code we can't read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a new label every time the cell gets reused and displayed again.

Since you're using a custom cell already, the easiest solution would be to give the cell a `UILabel` property, and use that instead of adding a new label each time. Specifically, you should only add a new label if you're creating a cell instead of getting a recycled one. Or, you could add a new `UILabel` only if the property is nil.

Comment: Im not declaring a new label every time, I am doing as you say and have a property for the label in my custom cell class.

Comment: Then why are you adding it as a subview each time?

Comment: Because if I don't add it as a subview then it doesn't show up. I have declared it and given it a property in my custom class, which is why Im partially unsure whats going on.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you should only add it as a subview the first time. Two options: 1) create and add the UILabel only when you are creating a cell from scratch (as opposed to getting a recycled cell) 2) create and add the UILabel only if there isn't an existing UILabel (i.e., the property is nil).

Answer (score 1):

Or as an alternative to adding the label in the custom class, just make sure to add the label inside the conditional cell creation. e.g.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];

if(cell == nil){
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease]; 
   [cell.contentView addSubview:[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease]];   // <-------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to the label, then check if it exists

```
UILabel *label;    
if ([cell viewWithTag:2]){
    label = [cell viewWithTag:2];}
else{
    label = [[UILabel alloc]init];label.tag = 2;}
```